# define a function in which min() is used

Tags: function, jupyter-notebook, min

I am trying to define a function in which I want a part of the function limited. I try to do this by using `min()` but it returns

```
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

My code:

```
def f(x, beta):
    K_w = (1+((0.5*D)/(0.5*D+x))**2)**2
    K_c = min(11,(3.5*(x/D)**(-0.5)))   # <-- this is what gives me the problem. It should limit K_c to 11, but that does not work.
    K_tot = (K_c**2+K_w**2+2*K_c*K_w*np.cos(beta))**0.5
    return K_tot

x = np.linspace(0, 50, 100)
beta = np.linspace(0, 3.14, 180)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, beta)
Z = f(X, Y)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.contour3D(X, Y, Z, 100, cmap = 'viridis')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z');
```

I expected `K_c` to be limited to 11, but it gave a

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I might be making a rookie mistake, but help is much appreciated!

Comment: In `min(11,(3.5*(x/D)**(-0.5)))`, 11 is single number while the second term is python series. How you are comparing single number with series? Do you want to compare 11 with the minimum number from the whole series?

Comment: I want to compare each number of the python series with the value 11 and select the smallest of those two numbers.

Comment: Here is the way to compare minimum of the Series with the number `min(11,(3.5*(x/D)**(-0.5)).min())`

Answer (score 0):

Consider using np.clip of which its references can be found [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html).

```
np.clip(3.5*(x/D)**(-0.5), None, 11)
```

for your case.

For example,

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.clip([1, 2, 3, 15], None, 11)
array([ 1,  2,  3, 11])
```

The problem with your code is that min is comparing a number with a list of which this is not expected.

Alternatively, here is a list comprehension approach:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 15]
B = [min(11, a) for a in A]
print(B)
```